# OpenCV 'cvtColor' changes color and saturation when executed multiple times (python)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I am using OpenCV's function `cv2.cvtColor` to modify an image in steps:

- I convert the original BGR image to HSV color format.
- I do some computation on HSV image.
- I convert back the HSV image to BGR color format.

Eventually, the converstion BGR-to-HSV and HSV-to-BGR is not prefectly dual and some (random) pixels see variations in their H and S values.

Here what I mean:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Load image
original_img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img = original_img.copy()


# Convert image multiple times
for ii in range(50):
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    print(f'\niter {ii+1}')
    print(f'H sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,0])}')
    print(f'S sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,1])}')
    print(f'V sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,2])}')


# Display images (resize for convenience)
cv2.imshow('original', cv2.resize(original_img, tuple([s*3 for s in img.shape[:2]])))
cv2.imshow('converted', cv2.resize(img, tuple([s*3 for s in img.shape[:2]])))

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original (left) vs converted (right):

[image: Original image]
[image: Converted image]

As you may notice, there are a bunch of pixels that becomes reddish and with an increasing saturation. Also, H and S channels change as (sum of values):

```
iter 1
H sum: 862253
S sum: 1470471
V sum: 1028930

iter 2
H sum: 847617
S sum: 1511497
V sum: 1028930

...

iter 49
H sum: 796974
S sum: 1570406
V sum: 1028930

iter 50
H sum: 796974
S sum: 1570412
V sum: 1028930
```

Python 3.8.3 | OpenCV 4.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the images are 8-bit, there is loss of data in each iteration.
See [convertion between HSV and RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).
For example, saturation is chroma (max - min) over maximum component.
When it is converted to HSV, the saturation value will be quantized between 0 to 255.
As a side note, the maximum hue value in OpenCV is 180.

Instead of using `uchar`, performing convertions with floating point images prevents the loss. I changed your code with `.astype(np.float32)` and the result is the same in each iteration.

```
H sum: 1739456.625
S sum: 5764.1796875
V sum: 1028930.0
```

Edited code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Load image
original_img = cv2.imread('img.png').astype(np.float32)
img = original_img.copy()


# Convert image multiple times
for ii in range(50):
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    print(f'\niter {ii+1}')
    print(f'H sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,0])}')
    print(f'S sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,1])}')
    print(f'V sum: {np.sum(img_hsv[:,:,2])}')


# Display images (resize for convenience)
cv2.imshow('original', cv2.resize(original_img, tuple([s*3 for s in img.shape[:2]])).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow('converted', cv2.resize(img, tuple([s*3 for s in img.shape[:2]])).astype(np.uint8))

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you @Burak. Despite it solves the original problem I introduced, your solution also leads to a strange behavior. Unfortunately I am not able to replicate it out of the specific computation I am doing on image. Short story is that I arrive at the final conversion (HSV to BGR) with a matrix image. If it's `uint8` conversion is ok, if it's `float32`, though exactly equal to its `uint8` twin, I get random negative values in output image. In BGR, max val is +255, min val is -32.500, mean val is -4480. When moving back to `uint8` I get a completely messed up image in most of the pixels.

Comment: @ALai I can't say I totally understand what you mean but the issue may be related to float-uint cast. Are you sure there are negative values in float format? If not, try using a `round` function before the cast.

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are negative values because I've directly looked at the image matrix. As I told you, I am not able to replicate the issue out of the specific computation I am doing, even repeating the same elaboration steps I am doing in my application, which is really strange.